# Filtering data source for Bokeh plot using MultiChoice and CustomJS

Tags: javascript, bokeh, bokehjs

To preface, I have never used JavaScript. After hours of searching I still do not quite understand how to solve my particular problem.

I have been utilizing bokeh to make interactive plots for a little while, and have used pandas to filter the data as seen in the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
df['sample'] =np.random.randint(1,3,9)
df['x'] = np.random.randint(0,10,9)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(0,10,9)

plot = figure(width=400, height=400)

for name in df.name.unique():
    
    source = ColumnDataSource(df[df['name']==name].groupby(['sample']).median())
    plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source, legend_label=name)

plot.legend.click_policy="hide"
plot.legend.background_fill_alpha = 0.25

show(plot)
```

The problem I have with this is that if I have too many names then the legend gets long and the plot gets messy. I tried to resolve this by adding a MultiChoice widget where the user selects which names to filter the data by and plot, while using a CustomJS callback to adjust the data source. I run in to a problem since I need to filter the data by 'name', then group by 'sample' and find that median of those points.

I suppose my lack of JS knowledge is leaving me a little lost here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT (Updates and clarification): Here is another attempt that I haven't gotten to work. Through the console log it appears that the source changes as I make selections on the MultiChoice widget. My plot however does not change. Also I need this to work with html, I can't use a bokeh server in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, MultiChoice
from bokeh.layouts import row

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
df['sample'] =np.random.randint(1,3,9)
df['x'] = np.random.randint(0,10,9)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(0,10,9)

plot = figure(width=400, height=400)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

initial_value = [df.name[0]]
options = list(df.name.unique())
multi_choice = MultiChoice(value=initial_value, options=options, max_items=3, title='Selection:')

temp_choice_dict = {}
for name in df.name.unique():
    if name == 'a':
        choice_dict = {'name': name}
    else:
        temp_choice_dict = {'name': name}
    for key, value in temp_choice_dict.items():
            choice_dict=set_key(choice_dict,key,value)
            
source_name = ColumnDataSource(name_dict)

if source_name.data['name']==[]:
    source_empty = ColumnDataSource({'x':[],'y':[]})
    plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source_empty)
else:
    for i in range(len(source_name.data['name'])):

        source = ColumnDataSource(df[df['name']==source_name.data['name'][i]].groupby(['sample']).median())
        plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source, legend_label=source_name.data['name'][i])

plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source)

callback = CustomJS(args={'source_name':source_name},code="""  
        console.log(' changed selected option', cb_obj.value);
        source_name.data['name'] = cb_obj.value;
        console.log(' source change', source_name.data['name']);
        source_name.change.emit();
""")


multi_choice.js_on_change('value', callback)

plot.legend.background_fill_alpha = 0.25

show(row(plot,multi_choice))
```

Comment: You could use backend, curdoc to do that and you dont have to know js for that.

Comment: Would this work if I am saving the figures in an html? I wasn't able to get that method to work from the other examples I had looked at.

Comment: no, not with html. as a said it works backend. check bokeh serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find some help over on the bokeh forum. The solution was to adjust the visibility of the selected glyphs and legend labels. A full solution is down below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, MultiChoice

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
df['sample'] =np.random.randint(1,3,9)
df['x'] = np.random.randint(0,10,9)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(0,10,9)

plot = figure(width=400, height=400)


name_dict={'name':[],'legend':[],'label':[]}
for name in df.name.unique():  
    source = ColumnDataSource(df[df['name']==name].groupby(['sample']).median())
    name_glyph = plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source, legend_label=name)
    name_dict['name'].append(name_glyph)
    name_dict['label'].append(name)

name_legend_dict={'name':[]}
for label in range(len(df.name.unique())):
    name_dict['legend'].append(plot.legend.items[label])
    
# Set up MultiChoice widget
initial_value = [df.name[0]]
options = list(df.name.unique())
multi_choice = MultiChoice(value=initial_value, options=options, max_items=3, title='Selection:')

for i in range(len(options)):
    if name_dict['label'][i] in initial_value:
        name_dict['name'][i].visible = True;
        name_dict['legend'][i].visible = True;
    else:
        name_dict['name'][i].visible = False;
        name_dict['legend'][i].visible = False;   
    

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(name_dict=name_dict, multi_choice=multi_choice), code="""
var selected_vals = multi_choice.value;
var index_check = [];

for (var i = 0; i < name_dict['name'].length; i++) {
    index_check[i]=selected_vals.indexOf(name_dict['label'][i]);
        if ((index_check[i])>= 0) {
            name_dict['name'][i].visible = true;
            name_dict['legend'][i].visible = true;
            }
        else {
            name_dict['name'][i].visible = false;
            name_dict['legend'][i].visible = false;
        }
    }
""")

multi_choice.js_on_change('value', callback)

plot.legend.background_fill_alpha = 0.25

show(row(plot,multi_choice))
```