# Bokeh and grid plot with arbitrary entries, MultiChoice & CustomJS for changing data

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh, interactive

I am trying to represent data organized as a matrix of vector-valued timeseries. Given a vector timeseries placed at position (i,j) in the matrix, the scalar timeseries components are obtained by some parameter 'order'. The size of the matrix is arbitrary and cannot be hard-coded. I want to

- plot each entry (timeseries) of the matrix,
- change which component of the timeseries is represented, using Bokeh's MultiChoice callback and updating *all* plots simultaneously.

I managed to do what I want on an example where the callback is written explicitly for each component of my matrix, by adapting an example seen here: [Filtering data source for Bokeh plot using MultiChoice and CustomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808303/filtering-data-source-for-bokeh-plot-using-multichoice-and-customjs)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, MultiChoice

# Generate some data structure
tau = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
N = 2
orders = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for o in orders:
    df_o = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            df_o[f'{i}{j}'] = i+j + np.cos(tau+o)
    df_o['order'] = str(o)
    df_o['tau'  ] = tau
    df = df.append(df_o,ignore_index=True)

# Bokeh plot
order_dict = {}
plots = []
for i in range(N):
    plots_line_i = []
    for j in range(N):
        plot_ij = figure(width=400, height=400)
        name_ij = f'{i}{j}'
        order_dict[name_ij] = {'order':[],'label':[]}
        for order in df.order.unique():  
            source = ColumnDataSource(df[df['order']==order])
            order_glyph_ij = plot_ij.line('tau', name_ij, source=source)
            order_dict[name_ij]['order'].append(order_glyph_ij)
            order_dict[name_ij]['label'].append(order)
        plots_line_i.append(plot_ij)
    plots.append(plots_line_i)

# Set up MultiChoice widget
initial_value = [df.order[0]]
options = list(df.order.unique())
multi_choice = MultiChoice(value=initial_value, options=options, max_items=3, title='Selection:')

# Set up callback: how to automatically loop within the dict keys '00', '01', '10', '11' ?
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(order_dict=order_dict, multi_choice=multi_choice), code="""
var selected_vals = multi_choice.value;
var index_check = [];

for (var i = 0; i < order_dict['00']['order'].length; i++) {

    index_check[i]=selected_vals.indexOf(order_dict['00']['label'][i]);
        if ((index_check[i])>= 0) {
            order_dict['00']['order'][i].visible = true;
            }
        else {
            order_dict['00']['order'][i].visible = false;
        }
    }

for (var i = 0; i < order_dict['11']['order'].length; i++) {
    index_check[i]=selected_vals.indexOf(order_dict['11']['label'][i]);
        if ((index_check[i])>= 0) {
            order_dict['11']['order'][i].visible = true;
            }
        else {
            order_dict['11']['order'][i].visible = false;
        }
    }

for (var i = 0; i < order_dict['01']['order'].length; i++) {
    index_check[i]=selected_vals.indexOf(order_dict['01']['label'][i]);
        if ((index_check[i])>= 0) {
            order_dict['01']['order'][i].visible = true;
            }
        else {
            order_dict['01']['order'][i].visible = false;
        }
    }

for (var i = 0; i < order_dict['10']['order'].length; i++) {
    index_check[i]=selected_vals.indexOf(order_dict['10']['label'][i]);
        if ((index_check[i])>= 0) {
            order_dict['10']['order'][i].visible = true;
            }
        else {
            order_dict['10']['order'][i].visible = false;
        }
    }
""")
multi_choice.js_on_change('value', callback)

# Display the grid plot
rows = []
for i in range(N):
    rows.append(row(*plots[i]))
show(column(*rows,multi_choice))
```

This code normally shows a 2x2 matrix plot:

[image: 2x2 matrix plot]

In the above code, you will see four 'for' loops in the JavaScript code (one for each entry '00', '01', '10', '11') of the matrix. Would it be possible to **do that automatically** by somehow going through the keys of the dictionary 'order_dict' ?

This may be a stupid question, but I don't know JavaScript so I'm having trouble debugging my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your JS-Code to

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(order_dict=order_dict, multi_choice=multi_choice), code="""
var selected_vals = multi_choice.value;
var index_check = [];
for (var k in order_dict){
    for (var i = 0; i < order_dict[k]['order'].length; i++) {
        index_check[i]=selected_vals.indexOf(order_dict[k]['label'][i]);
        order_dict[k]['order'][i].visible = index_check[i] >= 0
    }
}
""")
```

This is working exactly the same like your code.

The solution is based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913675/how-to-iterate-keys-values-in-javascript).

#### Comment

Your python code gives my a deprecation warning using pandas 1.4.+.

> FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

You can avoid this, changing

```
df = df.append(df_o,ignore_index=True)
```

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_o],ignore_index=True)
```

If you don't see this warning, you should consider to update your pandas version.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Regarding the warning, indeed my Pandas version was 1.3.5